# Storing an array in a Firebase Database

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store an array in the Firebase Database, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

I am wanting to store an array such as:

```
var exampleArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

The reason why is I populate a UIPicker with values from an array, and rather than having to push an update to the app each time to add a new value, it would be better if I could just update the database and instantly add the new value to each app.

Is there any way that I could store the values in the database and pull the values from the database and store it into an array as shown above?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a very comprehensive article on this subject: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase `setValue` method will accept an array just the same as a String or Integer. So you can read and write the values in the same way -

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()

var exampleArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

// Write the array 
ref.child("myArray").setValue(exampleArray)

// Read the array 
ref.child("myArray").observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    // Add the values to your picker array here
  }
}
```

Comment: I am wanting to manually add the values into the database, but I'm not sure how I can structure it as I've never added an array before. Would you please be able to give me an example?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "manually"? Do you mean appending values to an existing array?

Comment: Apologies, I meant through the firebase web control panel. You have written the array to the database as an example under the 'Write the array' section, but I am unsure how that would look within the database once it has been written. I want to skip that part, add the values to the database and just read them.

Comment: how about storing array of class object ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be read JSON from a Firebase Database Reference containing the array, and deserealize it in swift to a native swift array. See point 2 at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/#implementation_path